# vertx and handlebars how to register custom helpers

Tags: vert.x

The only vert.x reference documentation about handlebars [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_handlebars_template_engine) does not mention anything about registering custom handlebars helpers.

Also [HandlebarsTemplateEngine](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/reactivex/ext/web/templ/handlebars/HandlebarsTemplateEngine.html) API does not provide anything related with helpers.

Should we instantiate `Handlebars` directly through `Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars()` and register in `handlebars` rather than using `engine` from vert.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HandlebarsTemplateEngine` is just the glue required to get `Handlebars` to work with the rest of the vert.x modules. To fully customize your engine you can always get it's internal engine object.

With vert.x 4, this has been improved by the adition of the `unwrap()` method:

```
HandlebarsTemplateEngine vertxHBS = HandlebarsTemplateEngine.create(vertx);
Handlebars handlebars = vertxHBS.unwrap();
```

From here you can use the official API to customize the engine. The engine used is available here: https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java

To know how to register helpers follow the manual: https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java#registering-helpers

Here's a simple example:

```
HandlebarsTemplateEngine vertxHBS = HandlebarsTemplateEngine.create(vertx);

Handlebars handlebars = vertxHBS.unwrap();
// register a custom helper:
handlebars.registerHelper("blog", new Helper<Blog>() {
  public CharSequence apply(Blog blog, Options options) {
    return options.fn(blog);
  }
});
```